# PHP better to (un)serialize or redeclare a class?

Tags: php, performance, class, serialization

I've got a class which is used in several pages, but none of its data needs to be persistent.

Is it better practice (or performance) to

A) `include` and redefine the class each time I use it, or

B) serialize it into a session variable the first time and unserialize it when necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need its state, you don't need to ever serialise it.

Just `include` it when you need to, or take advantage of class autoloading. [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* unserialize a class which has not been defined. PHP will throw an error at you.

You must necessarily include the class definition.